# Windows Default Icon shown on MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

In the `MainWindow` constructor, before showing my `MainWindow`, I'm doing some checks that could prompt a `MessageBox` dialog. When this happens, an ugly Windows Default Icon is showing up in the Windows taksbar with the message box title beside.

I already set an Icon for my application in Properties -> Applicaton -> Resources -> Icon.

I tried to call `InitializeComponent()` before calling `MessageBox.Show`, but it doesn't change anything.

Once my application is fully launched (I exit the `MainWindow` constructor), the proper icon appears in the taskbar.

Is there a way to prevent this ugly icon from showing at all, or to replace it with my own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should only happens en Debug time. Try running with ctrl+f5, or excecuting the .exe file directly.

Comment: Right ! Using Ctrl+F5 does the job !

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, go to properties of your form, set the Icon to the one you wish ALSO go to 
Project > (name of project) Properties > Applications (tab) and set Icon there (at the bottom). Also you can change the icon of the messagebox with

```
MessageBox.Show("Foo", "Bar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

*Read more **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon(v=vs.110).aspx)***

Answer (score 0):

if you are using visual studio.....go to properties window and change the icon property

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not show the message box from within the constructor. At this time the object (the form) is not fully created yet.

Try the form's `Load` event instead.

Comment: After reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/501556) I prefer to override the [OnLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx) method instead.